# C++ function reference template substitution error with default type

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
std::string stringify (const T& value)
{ return "dummy"; }

template<typename T>
class foo_class
{
public:
    template<typename Converter = std::string(&)(const T&),
            class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<
                                                    typename std::result_of<Converter(const T&)>::type,
                                                    std::string>
                                            ::value>::type>
    foo_class(const T &value, const Converter &converter = stringify<T>) {}
};

int main(int,const char*[])
{
    int X = 7;
    foo_class<int> x(X);
    foo_class<int> y(X, stringify<int>);
}
```

The first constructor compiles just fine, however the second one fails with the following error under Clang 3.6.2:

```
candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with Converter = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (const int &)]: function cannot return function type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (const int &)'
    foo_class(const T &value, const Converter &converter = stringify<T>) {}
```

I dug down and found one way to fix it, by changing `const Converter &` to just `Converter` in the parameter list, although this might not be the desired behavior in some cases.

The error is caused by something in the std::enable_if<..> clause. I can remove it and the code compiles (and runs) just fine.

I am primarily interested in the question "why" - why does it work in the first case (when the function is selected as a default parameter), but not in the second case, when it is selected explicitly.

As a secondary question, what would be considered the best way to deal with the issue? I mean, I have one workaround, but would prefer to stick to the "const reference by default" policy for arguments that are not functions.

Comment: Another workaround is: `foo_class<int> y(X, &stringfy<int>);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you are supposed to use `result_of`.

It should always be used with references, where the kind of the reference designates the value category of the corresponding expression in the call whose result you want to know.

So if you are calling `converter` as a `const` lvalue, then you'd do `result_of<const Converter &(const T&)>`. A few more examples:

```
// forward the value category of the function object
template<class F> 
auto f(F&& f) -> std::result_of_t<F&&()> { return std::forward<F>(f)(); }

// always call as an lvalue, accept both lvalue and rvalue function object
template<class F> 
auto f(F&& f) -> std::result_of_t<F&()> { return f(); }

// Accept everything by value, but call with all lvalues
template<class F, class... Args> 
auto f(F f, Args... args) -> std::result_of_t<F&(Args&...)> { return f(args...); }

// Accept everything by value, and move them all
template<class F, class... Args> 
auto f(F f, Args... args) -> std::result_of_t<F&&(Args&&...)> { return std::move(f)(std::move(args)...); }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second snippet, you have

```
Converter = std::string(const T&) // without reference
```

2 possibles fixes/workarounds:

Use `std::decay_t`

```
template<typename T>
class foo_class
{
public:
    template<typename Converter = std::string(&)(const T&),
             std::enable_if_t<
                 std::is_convertible<
                     std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<Converter>(const T&)>,
                     std::string>::value>* = nullptr>
    foo_class(const T &value, const Converter &converter = stringify<T>) {}
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45231b84128ac411)

or use

```
foo_class<int> y(X, &stringfy<int>);
```

Comment: Or use `Converter = std::string(const T&)` and `Converter const&` in the `result_of` clause?